# How to create a glow animated circle that surrounds a sphere

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

I want to create an animation similar with this one; I am wonder how to create this glow animation effects ?

I do not know how to create the glow animated circle that surrounds the sphere; How to create this effects?

[image]

Comment: Where exctly are you stuck? Looks like with a bit of fog and an emission shader you should achieve a pretty simlar result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use object vertex positions to make a ring (math node set to absolute makes it a ring for example if you choose z value from vertex position every vertex with value more than 1 is white and with absolute node -1 and less values also means white and you can move positions before that ,so ring moves along z axes **this(the marked value) is also what you can keyframe to animate ring movement** ) then use the ring as a texture and map node to rotate it and use it as a factor to mix diffuse and emission shaders and also use some another axes like x to change ring color based on it.

[image]
there are some options to make glowing effect but this is an easy way, first check emission
[image]
in compositing blur emission part and mix it with rendered image
[image]